# Select encompassing rows

Tags: oracle, where

I have a `ROAD` table that has a row for each vertex of each line:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| ROAD_ID | VERTEX_INDEX | MEASURE_VAL |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       1 |            1 |           0 |
|       1 |            2 |         1.2 |
|       1 |            3 |         2.8 |
|       1 |            4 |         4.0 |
|       1 |            5 |         4.3 |
|       1 |            6 |         6.7 |
|       1 |            7 |         7.1 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       2 |            1 |           0 |
|       2 |            2 |         5.2 |
|       2 |            3 |         7.7 |
|       2 |            4 |         9.6 |
|       2 |            5 |        11.8 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       3 |            1 |           0 |
|       3 |            2 |         2.4 |
|       3 |            3 |         4.9 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

And an `EVENT` table with rows that pertain to portions of roads:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+------------+
| EVENT_ID | ROAD_ID | FROM_MEASURE | TO_MEASURE |
+----------+---------+--------------+------------+
|       01 |       1 |          2.8 |        5.9 |
|       02 |       2 |          3.0 |        5.6 |
|       03 |       3 |            0 |        2.6 |
+----------+---------+--------------+------------+
```

I want to select the vertices from `ROAD` where the `MEASURE_VAL` encompasses/contains the `EVENT` table's `FROM_MEASURE` and `TO_MEASURE` (including the vertices in between):

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| ROAD_ID | VERTEX_INDEX | MEASURE_VAL |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       1 |            3 |         2.8 |
|       1 |            4 |         4.0 |
|       1 |            5 |         4.3 |
|       1 |            6 |         6.7 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       2 |            1 |           0 |
|       2 |            2 |         5.2 |
|       2 |            3 |         7.7 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       3 |            1 |           0 |
|       3 |            2 |         2.4 |
|       3 |            3 |         4.9 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

In other words, I want to select vertices from `ROADS` where the `MEASURE_VAL` is between the event `FROM_MEASURE` and `TO_MEASURE`, and if the `MEASURE_VAL` does not exactly equal the `FROM_MEASURE` or `TO_MEASURE`, then also include the preceding and/or following vertices (where applicable).

Said yet differently again, I want to select the portion of the line that contains the event.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the `measure_val` is exactly equal to a `from _measure` (eg 2.8 and 2.8)? Should the previous value (`1.2`) be included in the result as well?

Comment: That's a good point. No, when the `measure_val` is exactly equal to a `from_measure` (eg 2.8 and 2.8), the previous value (1.2) should not be included in the result. This would apply to the `to_measue` as well. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I have changed the `measure_val` for road #1, vertex #3 from 2.7 to 2.8 to reflect this scenario. I will make note of this requirement in the question shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just simply get the previous and next measure values with `LAG` and `LEAD`, and filter based on them:

```
select road_id, vertex_index, measure_val from (
  select
    r.road_id, r.vertex_index, r.measure_val, e.from_measure, e.to_measure,
    lag(r.measure_val, 1, r.measure_val) over 
      (partition by e.road_id order by r.vertex_index) as prev_measure_val,
    lead(r.measure_val, 1, r.measure_val) over 
      (partition by e.road_id order by r.vertex_index) as next_measure_val
  from
    road r join event e on (r.road_id = e.road_id)
) where prev_measure_val <= to_measure and next_measure_val >= from_measure;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way, similar to @Balasz's answer but doing the calculation in reverse order. First calculating the "to"  value in the `road` table and then joining to `event`.

This query will give us for every row of the `road` the next ("to") value:

```
select road_id, vertex_id, measure_val,
       lead(measure_val) over (partition by road_id 
                               order by measure_val) 
           as to_measure_val 
from road ;

+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| ROAD_ID | VERTEX_INDEX | MEASURE_VAL | TO_MEASURE_VAL |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
|       1 |            1 |           0 |            1.2 |
|       1 |            2 |         1.2 |            2.8 |
|       1 |            3 |         2.8 |            4.0 |
|       1 |            4 |         4.0 |            4.3 |  
|       1 |            5 |         4.3 |            6.7 |
|       1 |            6 |         6.7 |            7.1 |
|       1 |            7 |         7.1 |           NULL | 
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
|       2 |            1 |           0 |            5.2 |
|       2 |            2 |         5.2 |            7.7 |
|       2 |            3 |         7.7 |            9.6 |
|       2 |            4 |         9.6 |           11.8 |
|       2 |            5 |        11.8 |           NULL |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
|       3 |            1 |           0 |            2.4 |
|       3 |            2 |         2.4 |            4.9 |
|       3 |            3 |         4.9 |           NULL |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Then we can join this to the `event` table so the `ON` condition basically checks **whether** the two "(from, to)" **intervals overlap** or not:

```
with r as 
  ( select road_id, vertex_id, measure_val,
           lead(measure_val) over (partition by road_id 
                                   order by measure_val) 
               as to_measure_val
    from road
  ) 
select
   r.road_id,
   r.vertex_id, 
   greatest(r.measure_val, e.from_measure) as from_val,
   case when r.to_measure_val is null 
            then e.to_measure 
            else least(r.to_measure_val, e.to_measure)
   end as to_val
from r
  join event e
    on  r.road_id = e.road_id
    and r.measure_val < e.to_measure  
    and (e.from_measure < r.to_measure_val or r.to_measure_val is null)
order by r.road_id, r.measure_val ;
```